# Releasing Apps to Apple App Store with Enterprise Program

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

Is it possible to release app with the public app store using an Enterprise program? As I understand it, this program is primarily for in house distribution.

We require a mixture of in house apps and public apps. Is it possible to distribute both with this program?

Comment: No, you will require two memberships; An enterprise program membership and an app store membership

Comment: Enterprise program is completely different, basically it made for B2B

Comment: Thanks, can I use the developer membership to distribute the app in house for testing purposes?

Comment: No you can not use enterprise provisioning profile to upload app to the app store. Enterprise is different program it use to build application for B2B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple Docs:

> The ability to distribute applications on the App Store is available
>   to developers who enroll in the iOS Developer Program as an Individual
>   or a Company. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program only allows you to
>   distribute your applications to employees or members of your
>   organization through Ad Hoc distribution. If your company is enrolled
>   in the Enterprise Program but would also like to distribute your
>   application(s) to customers via the App Store, you will need to enroll
>   in the iOS Developer Program as an Individual or as a Company.

Answer (score 0):

You can register one, personal developer account is used to list AppStore, and enterprise program is used for internal distribution.